# azure b2c using dynamics 365 as its storage & returning custom information

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, aad-b2c

We are investigating using Azure B2C.
We want to use dynamics 365 as the Azure B2C database but cannot find much documentation, and am asking for pointers or expertise.

- We want to use dynamics 365 as the database for azure B2C, so when a user signs up, a contact is created in Dynamics.
- We have a customized dynamics model. When a user authenticates, we want to return custom data from a custom entity. is this possible?

So far, we found documentation that says B2C can integrate with Dynamics for Customer Engagement, but that's very specific, and does not answer our questions.

If anyone has investigated this, appreciate some knowledge of your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring [Azure AD B2C as the Identity Provider for Dynamics 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-azure-ad-b2c-provider) is straightforward using Open ID Connect following the documentation. Any information you want to send to Dynamics must be included in output claims (either through custom policies or basic policy). This guide focuses on Basic Policies (you can tell since the policyID is starts with 'B2C_1_'. Advance/Custom policies start with 'B2C_1A_'. This is important depending on your complex sign-up account creation scenarios.

I recommend [compare User flows and custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview) before getting too far into your implementation.

More complex scenarios will require Custom Policies and you need to use the [Configure manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-azure-ad-b2c-provider-manual) documentation.

There are two common methods for creating accounts in Dynamics:

1. [Invite contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/invite-contacts) - a workflow triggered from Dynamics; this is more common when you need maximize control who gets access to your system. The entry point of the service has an out-of-band process to get access to your service in Dynamics
2. [Configure contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/configure-contacts) - this requires deprecating local identity provider as an option in Dynamics.

Review the [local authentication, registration and other settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/set-authentication-identity#disabled-registration) that will walk you through the different options to get your user onboarded.  Remember, information can be passed from Azure AD B2C to Dynamics through the token after authentication and populate the data in Dynamics but you need to configure the mapping for this outlined in the Dynamics documentation.